# Fastlane Deliver Screenshot Error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I'm trying to deploy my iOS app using Fastlane Deliver. I'm getting the following error.

```
[12:19:02]: Activating languages en-US, es-ES...
[12:20:02]: Sending crash report...
[12:20:02]: In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. In order to save your changes, all 9.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1024x768, 1024x748, 768x1024, 768x1004, 2048x1536, 2048x1496, 1536x2048 or 1536x2008 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. 3.5-inch display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format. In order to save your changes, all 5.5-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2208x1242 or 1242x2208 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 4.7-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 1334x750 or 750x1334 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. In order to save your changes, all 12.9-inch displays must be a .jpeg, .jpg, or .png file that is 2732x2048 or 2048x2732 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space. 4-inch display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format.
```

I'm running snapshot before hand so it should be uploading those images. It's a very generic error that doesn't provide very much detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by manually adding `Spanish (Spain)` as a language in iTunes Connect. Seems like a feature that Fastlane should handle automatically tho.